# Get all the files from a directory(on a shared path) and save them in wordpress uploads folder

Tags: php, wordpress

There is a directory on shared path, I'm scanning the directory for files, now what i need is to save each of this file in a single subfolder in uploads folder of wordpress. And insert the same post and attachments details of each file saved into db.

```
/*Function to List all the folders*/

    function listfolders($dir) {
        static $alldirs = array();
        $dirs = glob($dir . '/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);
        if (count($dirs) > 0) {
            foreach ($dirs as $d) $alldirs[] = basename($d);
        }
        foreach ($dirs as $dir) listfolders($dir);
        return $alldirs;
    }

    $folder_list = listfolders('D:\Base Folder');

/***Saving each FOLDER as TAG in wp_bdqueries_tags Table***/

    foreach($folder_list as $folder_name){
        $folder_slug = strtolower(preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $folder_name));
        echo $folder_name.'***'.$folder_slug.'<br>';


        /*global $wpdb;

        $wpdb->insert("wp_bdqueries_tags", array(
           "tag_group_id" => 27,
           "tag_name" => $folder_name,
           "tag_slug" => $folder_slug,
           "tag_status" => 'approved',
           "tag_description" => '',
           "tag_postedby" => 0 ,
           "tag_moderatedby" => 0,
           "tag_addedon" => date('Y-m-d h:i:s')
        ));*/
    }

/***Listing all the Files and thier FOLDERS/TAGS***/
    $directory = 'D:\Base Folder';
    $allfiles = array();

    $it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($directory));

    while($it->valid()) {

        if (!$it->isDot()) {

            $SubPath = $it->getSubPath();
            $tags = explode("\\", $SubPath);
            echo "Tags: ";
            foreach ($tags as $tag) {
                if($tag !== end($tags)) echo $tag.' | ';
                else echo $tag;
            }
            $path = $it->key();
            echo $path;
            echo '<br>Filename: <a href="'.$path.'" alt="Download" target="_blank" title="Download" >'. basename($path) . "</a><br>";
            $allfiles[] = basename($path);
            echo "<br>";
        }

        $it->next();
    } 
    echo '<ol>';
    foreach ($allfiles as $file) {
        echo '<li>'.$file.'</li>';
    }
    echo '</ol>';
```

Comment: What have you done so far? Post your code and results, and you'll have a far greater chance of getting a good answer to your question.

Comment: I need to save each of the file in a single folder in wordpress uploads folder, and insert the related data to each file in wp_posts and wp_postmeata table.
There is a repository from where i have to get all the files and save them in uploads folder, for now i have to run this script and save all the files, later have to write a cron job to regularly get and save the files from this repository

Comment: What happens when you run the above code? What's your output versus your expected output? The more details the better!

Comment: With this code I'm able to list all the files and also folders, what i need is to save each of these files in uploads folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using RecursiveIteratorIterator() function mentioned above i was able to retrieve all the files info from the Repository. 
Then using copy() method of php by passing the upload directory path and the target destination path i was able to copy/uploads the repository file to my custom uploads folder.